# How to set axis same in length in gnuplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I am making a map with gnuplot. But, I find that the length of X axis is not equal with the Y axis. For example, the length of X from 0 to 10 is 20 pixels while 15 pixels in Y axis from 1 to 10. Can I directly set X and Y axis same in length? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you mean the unit length of both axes, not the overall length -- at least if I interpret your comment to @fede.evol's answer correct. Please clarify this also in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sets the unit length of both axes to the same value:

```
set size ratio -1
```

Here is an excerpt from the documentation:

> `set size ratio <r>`
>   ...
>
> The meaning of a negative value for `<r>` is different.  If `<r>=-1`, gnuplot
>   tries to set the scales so that the unit has the same length on both the x
>   and y axes.  This is equivalent to `set view equal xy`.  See *set view equal*.
>   If `<r>=-2`, the unit on y has twice the length of the unit on x, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

> set size square

This should set the dimension (not scale) of the two axis to be equal.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I set different range of X and Y axis with 'set xrange [-15:15]; set yrange [-20:20]'. In this case, I can not get the same length X Y axis with 'set size square'.